# Is this perhaps a Dart bug?

Tags: dart

While trying to update a List of List of Strings in a map using the short notation with the fat arrow I get "This expression has type 'void' and can't be used." error. If I don't use the short notation and instead use an intermediate variable and return it it works fine.

I'm trying to update a map of the following type:

```
Map<String, List<List<String>>> mapWithAListOfListsOfStrings = {};
```

This is the code using the fat arrow notation.

```
void main() {
  Map<String, List<List<String>>> mapWithAListOfListsOfStrings = {};
  String string1 = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet';
  String string2 = 'consectetur adipiscing elit';

  for (String string in [string1, string2]) {
    List<String> splitString = string.split(' ');
    mapWithAListOfListsOfStrings.update('1', (list) => list.add(splitString), ifAbsent: () => [splitString]);
  }

  print("Map contains: ${mapWithAListOfListsOfStrings.toString()}");

}
```

This is the error I get:

```
sample.dart:8:56: Error: This expression has type 'void' and can't be used.
    mapWithAListOfListsOfStrings.update('1', (list) => list.add(splitString), ifAbsent: () => [splitString]);
```

This is my workaround that works:

```
void main() {
  Map<String, List<List<String>>> mapWithAListOfListsOfStrings = {};
  String string1 = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet';
  String string2 = 'consectetur adipiscing elit';

  for (String string in [string1, string2]) {
    List<String> splitString = string.split(' ');
    mapWithAListOfListsOfStrings.update('1', (list) {
      List<List<String>> returnList = list;
      returnList.add(splitString);
      return returnList;
    }, ifAbsent: () => [splitString]);
  }

  print("Map contains: ${mapWithAListOfListsOfStrings.toString()}");

}
```

And this is the desired result:

Map contains: {1: [[Lorem, ipsum, dolor, sit, amet], [consectetur, adipiscing, elit]]}

I'm happy to leave it like that. I just wonder why the first approach throws an error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is indeed that the return type of `list.add` is void, and not the list itself. The `update` method requires its argument function to return the new value for the provided key, and `=> list.add(...)` doesn't do that, it just returns void.

Your workaround could be reduced to:

```
(list) {
  list.add(splitString);
  return list;
}
```

or to:

```
(list) => list..add(splitString)
```

but the real problem is that you shouldn't be using `map.update` at all. That function is intended to *replace* the existing value for a key, not to keep the list value after adding something to it. You have to go out of your way to return the value again, instead of just using a function which doesn't change the value of the key (except if it isn't here).

I'd write it as:

```
mapWithAListOfListOfStrings.putIfAbsent('1', () =>[]).add(splitString);
```

The `putIfAbsent` returns the existing value, or inserts a value if there isn't one yet and then returns that value, so this really does:

- Ensure that my `map['1'] exists` and is a list
- Do `map['1'].add(splitString)`

It just does so without needing to look up `'1'` twice.

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive and very well explained answer as well as your elegant solution. Much appreciated!